# Parsley + Trying to validate Full-Width Text and Half-Width Text

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, parsley.js

Parsley + Trying to validate Full-Width Text and Half-Width Text

In email input box, parsley js should validate full-width / half-width, I am not getting the way to resolve this.

> For FullWidth Sample :- https://fullwidthtext.blogspot.in/

JS + Rails Code :-

```
<%=
  f.password_field :password,
  placeholder: 'Eight digit password',
  class: "form-control secondary_password",
  id:"user_raw_password",
  data: {
    parsley_required: "",
    parsley_minlength: "8",
    parsley_required_message: "Fill the input box"
  }
%>
```

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('validateEnglish', {
    validateString: function(_value) {
        regex = /[\u3000-\u303f\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\uff00-\uff9f\u4e00-\u9faf\u3400-\u4dbf]/;
        if (regex.test(_value)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Add above js validation to your parsley validations and Add `parsley_validate_english` validation to your field 
above function will help you rejecting non English characters